# Cannot decode tile_data in mbtiles

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, pbf

I downloaded the sample mbtiles data from  https://www.mapbox.com/help/data/trails.mbtiles

In the metadata of this file I found that the format is pbf.

[image]

But if I directly query the `tile_data` column in `images` table of it, and use some tools such as [vector-tile-base](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-base) to decode it, it will return errors with this message: `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag.` (I have tested the tool on some mvt files and it works with no problem)

So how should I get the decoded `pbf` data from `.mbtiles` files?

Appendix: 
Decoding code here:

```
import sqlite3
import vector_tile_base as vtb
tile_db = sqlite3.connect('trails.mbtiles')
cursor = tile_db.cursor()
one_example = cursor.execute('select tile_data from images limit 1').fetchall()[0][0]
vtb.VectorTile(one_example)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the specification of `mbtiles` from [this github url](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/6643d4daca3f7417e4f2068fb3974aadb0a1154d/1.3/spec.md) and finally find that in `mbtiles` files the pbf file is compressed by `gzip`, so it is neccessary to decompress it at first and then decode it using some protobuf tools.

```
import sqlite3
import vector_tile_base as vtb
import gzip
tile_db = sqlite3.connect('trails.mbtiles')
cursor = tile_db.cursor()
one_example = cursor.execute('select tile_data from images limit 1').fetchall()[0][0]
vtb.VectorTile(gzip.decompress(one_example[0]))
>>> <vector_tile_base.engine.VectorTile at 0x11f378eb8>
```

Comment: The official repo for `vector_tile_base` is [https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-base](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-base).

Comment: What is the proper way to use `vector_tile_base`? Do install in as a standalone package or do I install the entire `mapbox-vector-tile` package?